# TabWidget background color on Samsung devices

Tags: android-tabhost, android, android-tabs

My TabWidget's background color is light grey on HTC and Nexus devices...however it's blue-ish/dark grey on Samsung devices. Why is that? I'm even using a custom theme for the tabwidget, as created by android-holo-colors.com

Comment: FYI, I experienced the same thing, on 4.0.4 devices (using Tab Host).  I didn't find solution, but can confirm the issue is not just you.  I do use styles for these View elements.

Comment: see my answer below, I found a solution that's working fine for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the style and the layout for the tab:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
</style>

<style name="TabMyTheme">
  <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
  <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dip</item>
  <item name="android:paddingRight">16dip</item>
  <item name="android:background">@drawable/mytheme_tab_indicator_holo</item>
  <item name="android:layout_width">0dip</item>
  <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
  <item name="android:minWidth">80dip</item>
</style>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_host_default_height"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    style="@style/TabMyTheme"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@android:id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        style="@style/TabTextMyTheme" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I believe the problem is the fact that the default look of tabs is different for Samsung, and given that the background images generated by android-color-colors are transparent on top, and have the color just for the bottom part (ie: the thin or thick colored line at the bottom of each tab), on the top they just use the system default color.

I changed each and every image generated by the website, replacing the transparent color with my grey, and now it looks fine everywhere.